# Is there any other way to authentication the login page and route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first page set-up in angularjs. Everything worked fine until I tried to add routing. For some reason, I can't seem to route to the `Home screen`. My code is working is fine , but I couldn't route the page. Even i added `$location.path()` but it din't work.

This is my plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/9O5dHYZMKAqF07y7moVT

Here is my code : HTML

```
<div class="package col-md-12" ng-controller="credientials">

            <form ng-submit="loginform()"  class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label form="emailinput"><b>Email</b></label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" id="emailinput" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label form="pwdinput"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="pwdinput" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                </div>

                <a ng-click="reloadPage()" class="navbar-brand" title="home"></a>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="cancel" class="btn" ng-click="toggle_cancel()">Cancel</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="">Login</button>
                </div><br/> 
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ info }}</span>
            </form>
        </div>
```

AngularJs :

```
var app = angular.module('logapp',['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('credientials', function($scope,$route,$location,authentication) {

        $scope.Urltemplate =
        [
            { url: 'login.html' },
            { url: 'home.html'}
        ];
            $scope.template = $scope.Urltemplate[0];
            $scope.loginform = function (username, password) {
        if ( $scope.username === 'user@evol.com' && $scope.password === '1') {
            authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
            $scope.template = $scope.Urltemplate[1];
            $scope.user = username;
            $scope.info = authentication.isAuthenticated;
            $location.path("/home.html");
        } else {
            toastr.error('Invalid username and password');
        }
      };
});
```

Comment: 2 things. Change $location.path('home.html') to                     $location.path("/home"); '/home' is your registered route and secondly you're missing     <div ng-view></div>
in your index.html. This tells the routing to switch the views

Comment: @PrinayPanday. I corrected my mistake and made the changes. But when i include `ng-view` i am getting controller mismatch error. i don't know why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `ng-view` in html to use different routes

Here I have updated your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/7L6A6niKMQ4vn2OYP3LN?p=preview

You don't have some files which you are using in routes, I have change your home page for testing please update with yours

Comment: When i include `ng-view`, i got controller mismatch error.

Comment: Should i pass any value in `ng-view`

Comment: Controllers need to declared in route configuration...don't use ng-controller in html pages. For mode details check official documentation of [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: Thank you. But i have one small query. when i login , all the content in the main form is getting directed to other form page also. How could i stop it

Comment: When you change the route you don't have the scope for previous route data, maybe its coming from factory

Comment: do we have any solution for that